# libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, conda

I'm using a remote server where Python has been pre-installed.

```
ml python/3.7
```

Path of python:

```
whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/include/python2.7 /home-net/home-3/mchua4@jhu.edu/pathway_image/bin/python /home-net/home-3/mchua4@jhu.edu/anaconda3/bin/python3.9 /home-net/home-3/mchua4@jhu.edu/anaconda3/bin/python3.9-config /home-net/home-3/mchua4@jhu.edu/anaconda3/bin/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

I added the following line to the ~/.bashrc file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:~/anaconda3/envs/penv/bin/python3.7/lib/
```

However, python3 is still throwing an error:

```
python3
python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Path

```
which python
~/pathway_image/bin/python
```

Comment: can you try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib:~/anaconda3/envs/penv/bin/python3.7/lib/`?

Comment: @Marat It works for the first time but then it throws the same error again and disconnect me from the conda environment.